# GEE regression error: Image.reduce: ReduceBands reducer must have one input: <Reducer>

Tags: google-earth-engine, regression

I'm trying to run a basic linear regression between two variables in Google Earth Engine. I have a two-band image: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/stephenawood/reprexdata

To run a basic regression between the two variables and plot the results, I use the following code:

```
var linReg = reprexdata.reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit());
Map.addLayer(linReg);
```

This generates the following error:

```
Layer 1: Layer error: Image.reduce: ReduceBands reducer must have one input: <Reducer>.
```

Note, I get the same error if I try `print(linReg);` rather than to map it. If I only execute the line starting `var linReg` I don't get any error.

I can use other reducers without error. The following works without an error:

```
var means = reprexdata.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
Map.addLayer(means);
```

This seems like it must be an issue of not being able to compute the regression reducer for some reason that I can't figure out.

Comment: Could be that you are experiencing what some refer to as the multicollinearity problem in GWR. It really is an identical value issue. This is where all of the values in the search neighborhood are identical in y or x 1...n. Before putting too much effort into this, I would highly recommend looking at alternative methods. GWR is quite suspect and only really supported in exploratory data analysis. Besides, unless you truly have quantified spatial nonstationarity, this is not a correct model. GWR does not work well for first order spatial process as it is too localized.

Comment: @Kuik it executes, but it seems to lose a bunch of information by aggregating pixels together.